# Plotly fig.show() giving TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to plot multiple y axis graph using a dictionary and getting this error TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable. I have tried multiple attempts but can't plot the graphs. I'm using plotly version 2.7.0

Here is my complete script

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go


params_list = {



"spd": {
"plot-graph": [
  {
    "x-axis": [1,6,12],
    "y-axis": [.5,3,6],
    "y-axis-title": "y 0",
    "layout" : {
    "title" : "sample 1",
    "titlefont": "",
    "tickfont": "",
    "side": "",
    "overlaying": ""}
  },
  {
    "x-axis": [3,9,14],
    "y-axis": [4,2,9],
    "y-axis-title": "sample 2",
    "layout" : {
    "title": "y 2",
    "titlefont": "rgb(120, 113, 159)",
    "tickfont": "rgb(130, 103, 189)",
    "side": "right",
    "overlaying": "y"}
  },
  {
    "x-axis": [12, 10, 5],
    "y-axis": [8, 4, 11],
    "y-axis-title": "sample 3",
    "layout" : {
    "title": "y3",
    "titlefont": "rgb(112, 103, 189)",
    "tickfont": "rgb(110, 103, 189)",
    "side": "right",
    "overlaying": "y"}
}
]
}
}

plot_graph = []


listTrace = []

cnt = 0;

#graph with multiple y axes            

layout_kwargs = {'title' : "My TEST Graph"}            

graph_list = params_list['spd']['plot-graph']

graph_list = [{ k: v for k, v in d.items() if v } for d in graph_list]

cnt = 0       

for params in graph_list:
   trace = go.Scatter(x=params['x-axis'],y = params["y-axis"], name =          params["y-axis-title"], yaxis='y' + str(cnt + 1) * (cnt > 0))


   y_axis_name = 'yaxis' + str(cnt + 1) * (cnt > 0)
   layout = {k: v for k, v in params['layout'].items() if v }
   if layout.has_key('titlefont'):
       layout['titlefont'] = dict(color = layout['titlefont'])

   if layout.has_key("tickfont"):
       layout["tickfont"] = dict(color = layout['tickfont'])
   layout_kwargs[y_axis_name] = layout
       listTrace.append(trace)                
   cnt = cnt + 1

fig = go.Figure(data=listTrace, layout=go.Layout(**layout_kwargs))
fig.show()
```

Earlier the error was in go.Figure method but now it's in fig.show()...

Answer (score 1):

`fig.show()` was introduced in Plotly version 4 but you’re on version 2 as you mentioned above.